# Input individually clears the value of v-model

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Using vue, is there any way to clear the input value individually?
Because a lot of input will be used, writing in this way will have a lot of functions.
But you can’t use loops, because there are actually different fields

```
<input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="name"> 
<span @click="clearName()" v-if="this.name.length > 0">x</span>
<input v-model="email" type="text" placeholder="email"> 
<span @click="clearEmail()" v-if="this.email.length > 0">x</span>
<input v-model="address" type="text" placeholder="address"> 
<span @click="clearAddress()" v-if="this.address.length > 0">x</span>

method:{
  clearName(){
    this.name=''
  }
  clearEmail(){
    this.email=''
  }
  clearAddress(){
    this.address=''
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a common method name that accepts an argument. For example:

```
// JS

clearField(fieldName) {
  this[fieldName] = '';
}

// HTML

<input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="name"> 
<span @click="clearField('name')" v-if="this.name.length > 0">x</span>
<input v-model="email" type="text" placeholder="email"> 
<span @click="clearField('email')" v-if="this.email.length > 0">x</span>
<input v-model="address" type="text" placeholder="address"> 
<span @click="clearField('address')" v-if="this.address.length > 0">x</span>
```

Answer (score 2):

Make one function and pass the property name as parameter then access it using `[]` :

```
 clear(property){
    this[property]=''
  }
```

or just do an inline instruction :

```
 <input v-model="name" type="text" placeholder="name"> 
 <span @click="name=''" v-if="this.name.length > 0">x</span>
```